# C# equivalent to VB.NET 'Handles button1.Click, button2.Click'

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

In [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) I can do

> ```
> private sub button_click(sender, e) handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click etc...
> do something...
> end sub
> ```

Is there a method for this in C# .NET? I have roughly 16 buttons that all call the same function, just passing the text of the button to the function. I would rather not have 16 `private void button_clicks` calling one function.

I am not sure how to do this though (not familiar with C# to much.)

Comment: You should name your buttons.

Comment: These _could_ be sanitized names but I do agree with you @SLaks.

Comment: @SLaks the buttons are name - sorry I just named them button1 button2 etc. for the purpose of the post.

Comment: I hoped so, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: @SLaks I agree completely - I am big on naming conventions and hate reading/troubleshooting code that has no naming conventions. I actually took over a vb6 system from a guy that has dim x, a, b, c as string im almost every function. dim mainbuilderstring is something I despise. camel case buttonAction is my normal convention. Thanks though for pointing that out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Button1.Click += button_click;
Button2.Click += button_click;
```

Comment: I too came across this, what do we call this? for e.g. operator overloading? Or delegates? etc

Answer (score 7):

Manually, you can do this:

```
button1.Click += button_Click;
button2.Click += button_Click;
...
```

In the Designer, the Click event property is actually a drop-down menu where you can choose among existing methods that have the appropriate signature.

Answer (score 5):

C# does not have the `Handles` keyword.
Instead, you need to add the handlers explicitly:

```
something.Click += button_click;
somethingElse.Click += button_click;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
button1.Click += button_click;
button2.Click += button_click;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep it maintainable, I would go with something like this:

```
//btnArray can also be populated by traversing relevant Controls collection(s)
Button[] btnArray = new Button[] {button1, button2};
foreach(Button btn in btnArray) {
  btn.Click += button_Click;
}
```

Any refactoring to this code is done via a single point of maintenance. For example:

- You decide to bind to a custom button class with a custom event, i.e. MyClick.
- You decide to change logic of how buttons are collected, add or remove buttons.
- You figure button_Click is a bad name, or need to have conditional event binding.

Answer (score 1):

```
btn1.Click += button_click;
btn2.Click += button_click;
```

is the answer